# Pass model data to javascript function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this model `@model WebApplication1.Models.Person` which has an `Id` data. I want to pass `Id` to a javascript function via `<a href="#" onclick=myFunction(idGoesHere)>`.

I tried putting `@Model.id` or passing the value of `@Model.id` to another variable, but still it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to your JS function will look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('@Model.id')"> </a>
```

This will send the current `id` in concern to your JS function.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it was that easy.

Answer (score -2):

try to get raw value, and then use it

```
var userObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just return the model in a json string? How am I gonna get the id from that?

Comment: With this userObj.id

Comment: But that is returning all integers as 0